# PHP - Validate Multisig Bitcoin Wallet Address (with Leading 2 or 3)

Tags: php, bitcoin

I have used [this function](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=197407.msg2059485#msg2059485) for validating the bitcoin wallet address to see if it's a bitcoin address. However, it's not working with address that starts with "3" (multi-sig). For example, `3EktnHQD7RiAE6uzMj2ZifT9YgRrkSgzQX`.

Can anyone help me with that function to make it work that it can validate all major forms of bitcoin wallet addresses?

Comment: Your request is much too vague.  Have you verified that the function is appropriate for that address?  Are you getting errors?  Have you researched alternative functions?

Comment: @belwood I have tried to validate the example address. And it returns false at `if (hexdec(substr($address,0,2)) > 0) { return false; }`

Comment: I just tried that code on http://phpfiddle.org/ with a dozen different bitcoin addresses and yes, those beginning with 3 were a problem.  I know nothing about bitcoin aglos but maybe the code-poster's comment has some clue: "Minor correction.  There actually is no 'multisig addresses' just Pay2PubKeyHash addresses and Pay2ScriptHash addresses.  The code provided only properly handles the former"

Answer (score 1):

I just found this [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation#PHP): p

```
function validate($address){
        $decoded = decodeBase58($address);

        $d1 = hash("sha256", substr($decoded,0,21), true);
        $d2 = hash("sha256", $d1, true);

        if(substr_compare($decoded, $d2, 21, 4)){
                throw new \Exception("bad digest");
        }
        return true;
}
function decodeBase58($input) {
        $alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        $out = array_fill(0, 25, 0);
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($input);$i++){
                if(($p=strpos($alphabet, $input[$i]))===false){
                        throw new \Exception("invalid character found");
                }
                $c = $p;
                for ($j = 25; $j--; ) {
                        $c += (int)(58 * $out[$j]);
                        $out[$j] = (int)($c % 256);
                        $c /= 256;
                        $c = (int)$c;
                }
                if($c != 0){
                    throw new \Exception("address too long");
                }
        }

        $result = "";
        foreach($out as $val){
                $result .= chr($val);
        }

        return $result;
}

function main () {
  $s = array(
                "1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nK9",
                "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62i",
                "1Q1pE5vPGEEMqRcVRMbtBK842Y6Pzo6nJ9",
                "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62I",
        );
  foreach($s as $btc){
    $message = "OK";
    try{
        validate($btc);
    }catch(\Exception $e){ $message = $e->getMessage(); }
    echo "$btc: $message\n";
  }
}

main();
```

It does do multisig:

[image]

Comment: +1 @Frankenmint : Working awesome with different bitcoin provider like zebpay,bitstamp,coinsecure, blockchain.info...etc